# Div not wrapping around whole page in width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I use jQuery UI `tabs` as my container div. Now I need to show ALOT of data in a table, which will almost always be wider than the container itself. Unfortunately, I can't get the container to wrap.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJBkF/)

I have tried positions, `overflow: auto`, but nothing seems to work like I want it to. `overflow: auto` puts the horizontal scrollbar in the tabs itself, but I want it on the body. Anybody have an idea on how to do this?

**Long story short: I need the `#main-div` to wrap around all it's `div` childs, without a scrollbar in the tabs. I simply wanna wrap my content so the out div is dynamic with the content**

Comment: so let me get this straight you wanna be able to scroll inside the tab but the scroller on the window bottom? why not redesign the scroller so it have a more user friendly look? :)

Comment: @SimonPertersen I need to scroll the content from the tabs with a scrollbar on the body. I don't want to make this project too advanced, so I'm not going to redesign the scrollbar. This is now solved with CSS and it does exactly what it needs to do.

Comment: can i add that you need to post a clear question just look over what it is that you just wrote :) but it makes sense now

Comment: @SimonPertersen Normally my questions are a bit more clear. I guess it was just because it's monday and wanted it to be fixed fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RJBkF/6/) what you mean? All I did was this and removed the relative position.

```
#main-tabs
{
   float:left;
   min-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `#test { overflow: auto; }`

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/RJBkF/5/)

Comment: It does remove the scrollbar, yes, but I need to be able to scroll and I want the scrollbar on the body.

Comment: then `use oveflow:auto` instead of `oveflow:hidden`

Comment: Maybe it was a little bit unclear. I have updated my answer. Your answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
#main-tabs div
{
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it was a little bit unclear. I have updated my answer. Your answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJBkF/3/)

i added overflow:scroll;

anyhow here you get a scroll on both axis so you might look in to overflow scroll on x and y
Checkout the property [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) (be aware that its a css 3 property) dont know which browsers support it.

Comment: Maybe it was a little bit unclear. I have updated my answer. Your answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#test {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```